# How to make games for Android devices in Android Studios

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sprite-kit

I develop games for IOS devices and I wanted to make games for android devices as well. The problem is I dont think you can do it with Android Studios alone. correct ?

In IOS development we have Spritekit, which helps us make games and good ones.

Does Android Studios have anything similar to that ? I've looked up many sites and I cant find the answer. I see many android developers use Unity, buildblocks, etc. To make games. Is this the only way to make the games for android devices or can you make exact games like the ones in unity and Spritekit by only using Android Studios ?

Thank You In Advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely can create games with Android Studio alone -- creating your own game engine is one way.

If you mean using a ready game engine, an excellent alternative is libgdx - https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com - but there are others.

Comment: Would you recommend making your own game engine or using a ready game engine ?

Comment: Depends on your experience and goal. If your main goal is to make games, then use libgdx, it's awesome. If you like more to create libraries than making games with them, then make your engine. Making engines takes a lot of time and efforts, so you really must like that a lot.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your quick response I will check libgdx out !

Comment: @imerso libGDX is not a game engine, it is a small gaming framework.